# Cannot get key in JSON string, comes up null

Tags: objective-c, json

When outputting the entire parsed JSON object it works fine, however when trying to output the value of a key it comes up with `(null)`

The parsing code:

```
-(NSString *)getNews{

__block NSString *strReturn;

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL/URL.json"]];

__block NSDictionary *json;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:nil];

                               NSLog(@"Async JSON news: %@", json[@"ID"]);

                           //strReturn = json[@"ID"];
                       }];
return strReturn = @"Hello";

}
```

This here is from the JSON output file on the server;

`[{"ID":"1","Item Description":"Test News Item Active","News Text":"This is a test news story.\r\n\r\nit should have a few line breaks.\r\n\r\nbut that's about it.","Valid From":"2014-05-23 00:00:00","Valid To":"2014-09-30 23:59:59"}]`

Can anybody tell me why it is not finding the value of key `ID`?

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  This only takes 5-10 minutes, and then you will see that what you have above is an ARRAY containing a single JSON OBJECT.

Comment: Also, the `error` parm is there for a reason, and if you ignore it I will viciously downvote you.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have noted what you have all said, however I have another block the same for reading JSON (which isnt inside an array, so that must be the issue) that works. I will try looking into retrieving the value of an object in an array

Comment: Also, your method won't be able to return anything from your response the way you have it set up. Look into using callback blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Dictionary is inside an array. So you have to reference it correctly:

```
NSLog(@"Async JSON news: %@", [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"ID"]);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Only problem with this, is im now getting the error `No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares selector 'objectAtIndex'`

Comment: Because you are using an NSDictionary pointer for what is actually an NSArray.